# Angular2 Repeat item in reverse order

Tags: angular, typescript

How to repeat items in reverse order 
This is what I have done

```
 let newSearchTerm = this.getItem(this.searchHistoryKey)
      newSearchTerm.push({
        'q': this.searchTerm
      });

 this.setItem(this.searchHistoryKey, JSON.stringify(newSearchTerm));




<li *ngFor="let search of searchHistory"><span th-icon th-time>icon</span><a href="/"><label for="">{{search.q}}</label></a><span (click)="addHistory()" th-icon arrow-up>icon</span></li>
```

**I want to print the search in reverse order. How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

Could try using the array.reverse():

```
this.setItem(this.searchHistoryKey, JSON.stringify(newSearchTerm).reverse());
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(newSearchTerm).reverse() may reverse the string and not the object. I need to reverse the objects inside the newSearchTerm

Answer (score 0):

try this filter:

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});

...
...
...

*ngFor="let search of searchHistory | reverse"
```

Comment: right! refer this link for creating custom pipes in angular 2

Answer (score 0):

```
reverseJSON(jsonObj) {
      let reverseList = [];
      for (let i = jsonObj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseList.push(jsonObj[i]);
      }
      return reverseList;
    }
```

This Helped me. Did it in pure javascript.